# can't post form from ajaxsubmit - yii

Tags: php, yii

i've been having this problem for the second day. The form is not posting. I can't get passed `isset($_POST)`

Here I have the model showing:

```
public function actionResetPassword()
    {
        $model=new ResetPasswordRequest();      
        $this->render('resetpassword',array('model'=>$model));
    }
```

On click it takes me here:

```
public function actionRequestResetCode()
{
if(isset($_POST['ResetPasswordRequest']))
    { //never gets pass this
    }else // not set
```

And here is the view. It goes to success and tells me not set.

```
 <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email',array('id'=>'email')); ?>
         <?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton( 'Request', 
                CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('site/RequestResetCode')),
                array (
                    'type' => 'POST',
                    'dataType'=>'JSON',
                    'data'=> '$("#reset-email").serialize();',
```

Comment: Is `$_POST[]` completely empty? Do you see the post in firebug or some other tool?

Comment: `'data'=> '$("#reset-email").serialize();'` remove this. Just watch what event is binded in your js on body. And start to use firebug or chrome console for ajax.